# How to change the position of two screens in GoogleCardboardVR on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

Right now I am developing using GoogleVR SDK and Unity.
When I build a sample scene on my phone, the video is output in a form that splits the phone screen in half. Also, the center point is displayed on each side.

I would like to change the position, distance, and size of these two halves of the screen that are displayed on each side, and I would like to know how to do this.

(For example, I would like to distance the two images so that they are more optimized for people with larger IPD.)

I have checked the Api file and searched Google for a way to do this but could not find it.
Perhaps there is a drawing setting somewhere, but I could not find it.
The plugin I used is ↓.
"https://github.com/googlevr/cardboard-xr-plugin"

My current idea is to adjust the Viewport Rect in MainCamera.